# How to multiply columns in the same position from two different pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to multiple columns from the dataframes such that the same types appears in the same position of the dataframe. For example, in the dataframes below, `df1` colums and `df2` columns are essentially the same and comes in the same order. The only difference is that the `df2` columns have a suffix and the data type is float. The column positions matters in that the first column of df1 is a dichotomization of first column of df2. For a certain purpose, I need to multiply the value from df2 to dichotomized value from df1 for each column and then sum them row-wise. This should produce a single column with a sum that I need to use for something else.

**First dataframe:**

```
df1 = {'a': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 1},
 'b': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'c': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1},
 'd': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'e': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0},
 'f': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'g': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0},
 'h': {0: 1,
  1: 0,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 0},
 'i: {0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 0,
  3: 1,
  4: 0},
 'j': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1}}
```

**Second dataframe**

```
df2 = {'a_top3': {0: 0.084973365,
  1: 0.057013709,
  2: 0.072325557,
  3: 0.098824218,
  4: 0.252425998},
 'b_top3': {0: 0.168823063,
  1: 0.044829924,
  2: 0.178180799,
  3: 0.032501712,
  4: 0.054869764},
 'c_top3': {0: 0.040331405,
  1: 0.042758454,
  2: 0.077851109,
  3: 0.111247674,
  4: 0.160724968},
 'd_top3': {0: 0.11076121,
  1: 0.156901404,
  2: 0.111759722,
  3: 0.031440482,
  4: 0.046660293},
 'e_top3': {0: 0.059534989,
  1: 0.090733215,
  2: 0.087737411,
  3: 0.141953781,
  4: 0.011520214},
 'f_top3': {0: 0.067696713,
  1: 0.081674345,
  2: 0.034215827,
  3: 0.075849444,
  4: 0.011245198},
 'g_top3': {0: 0.041895844,
  1: 0.048191357,
  2: 0.102012217,
  3: 0.100579783,
  4: 0.034403443},
 'h_top3': {0: 0.124932915,
  1: 0.085968919,
  2: 0.220041335,
  3: 0.155145347,
  4: 0.032171372},
 'i_top3': {0: 0.103714436,
  1: 0.349804282,
  2: 0.077229746,
  3: 0.150859997,
  4: 0.081321001},
 'j_top3': {0: 0.197336018,
  1: 0.042124409,
  2: 0.038646296,
  3: 0.101597518,
  4: 0.314657748}}
```

I need a column such that it is a sum of product of each column in the same position. For example,

```
prod_sum = df1[['a','b','c']].mul(df2[['a_top3', 'b_top3', 'c_top3']], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
```

should produce the following:

[image]

The method I tried is shown above, but all I get is `NaN`. I can do this using loop, but curious to find out if there's a `pythonic` way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a subset of your data ( the first three columns of df1 and df2):

```
In [362]: temp1 = df1.loc[:, ['a','b','c']]
     ...: temp2 = df2.iloc[:, :3]

In [363]: temp1
Out[363]: 
   a  b  c
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  0
4  1  0  1

In [364]: temp2
Out[364]: 
     a_top3    b_top3    c_top3
0  0.084973  0.168823  0.040331
1  0.057014  0.044830  0.042758
2  0.072326  0.178181  0.077851
3  0.098824  0.032502  0.111248
4  0.252426  0.054870  0.160725
```

When multiplying (or any similar operation), Pandas will try and align the index and columns. In this scenario, we need to find a way to align the column names from `temp1` (a, b, c) to `temp2`(a_top3, ...). The simplest solution in this case is to drop the `top3` suffixes for `temp2`, Pandas will then successfully multiply the columns and return what you need:

```
In [367]: temp1.mul(temp2.rename(columns = lambda x: x[0])).sum(1)
Out[367]: 
0    0.168823
1    0.000000
2    0.178181
3    0.000000
4    0.413151
dtype: float64
```

Extending the same idea to `df1` and `df2` :

```
In [368]: df1.mul(df2.rename(columns = lambda x: x[0])).sum(1)
Out[368]: 
0    0.491092
1    0.597439
2    0.509982
3    0.447959
4    0.727809
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do by removing the "characters" from column to make it the same but couldn't figure out what to do. I had also tried `np.where()`, but ran into a problem there too. So, thank you for showing the way.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make use of `merge()` method:

```
result=df1[['a','b','c']].merge(df2[['a_top3', 'b_top3', 'c_top3']],left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Finally make use of `apply()` method and `anonymous function`:

```
result=result.apply(lambda x:x['a']*x['a_top3']+x['b']*x['b_top3']+x['c']*x['c_top3'],axis=1)
```

Now if you print `result` you will get:

```
0    0.168823
1    0.000000
2    0.178181
3    0.000000
4    0.413151
dtype: float64
```

Since the series contain `float` type data so you can't get `0` in place of `0.000000`

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. The only problem I had with this that it required me to type each individual column names. In my actual dataset, I have about 87 columns which would be pretty crazy to type every single one of them. But, thanks for attempting. I appreciate it